# How Can I Push a Shallow Cloned Git Subtree?

Tags: git, github, git-subtree

I have a repository that includes a subtree used to push deployment files to different remotes.

When setting the repository up fresh, I perform the following:

- Clone the repository.
- Add the remote(s) for the subtree.
- Fetch from the subtree remote.
- Commit and push to the main remote branch and subtrees as usual.

I recently attempted to reduce the size on local disk by adding the *--depth* parameter to the first and third steps.

Pushing to the main remote works OK, but I can no longer push to the subtrees. I get:

`error: failed to push some refs to '<repo>'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

Is there any mechanism to achieve this? I tried increasing the depth, but ultimately I had to *fetch --unshallow* from the remotes before I could push my subtree again.

My local Git version is 2.7 and the subtree remotes are 2.3. The main repository is on GitHub.